# Can Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Remote Desktop Services User CALs be used on Windows Server 2019 Standard?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, license, windows-server

My friend already has Windows Server 2019 Essentials but no RDS licenses yet. He wants to use several (more than two) parallel Remote Desktop connections. It seems it is not possible on Windows Server 2019 Essentials, unfortunately. Is this correct? Q1: Does my friend need a Windows Server 2019 Standard edition license?

While buying RDS licenses, it would be wise to buy Windows Server 2022 RDS licenses since they expire later than WS 2019 ([EOL Jan 2029](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server-2019)) - but... Q2: will they work with Windows Server 2019 Standard?

Comment: I did my best to fix the grammar in your question. Hopefully, I kept the essence of your question, in the future run your question through a grammar check before submitting it.

Comment: Windows Server 2019 and Windows Server 2022 are license independently. So if your friend purchased Windows Server 2022 RDS User Cals they can only be used with Windows Server 2022. Since your friend has Windows Server 2019 Essentials, and it does not meet his needs, at a minimum he would need to purchase Windows Server 2019 Standard or Windows Server 2022 Standard.

Answer (score 0):

yes they will. The licenses has downgrade rights. Downgrade rights are
granted with all server
software licenses acquired
through the Commercial
Licensing programs.